# Webpack 4 convert sass to css in the same folder

Tags: webpack

So i need to convert my sass files to css before i import them to react components.

Files needs to be converted from example.sass to example.css in the same folder just like gulp-sass does.

I've searched for hours and couldn't find a solution...

Thanks in advance.

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css',
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: can you try filename: "custom/my/folder/for/css/[name].css",

Comment: First: why can't you simply import sass files and let webpack handle everything? That is what you should do, since you are going with webpack!

Comment: Yes thats what i ended up doing, I didnt know you can just import sass files, Thanks